# What does it mean if my iPhone 12 isn't powering on?

Tags: iphone, ios, battery, charging, power

Today I received a brand new iPhone 12 mini. It won't power on, no matter what I try.

I tried charging it for a couple of hours, but when I hit the power button it still shows that it's dead or needs charged.

I'm just very confused about the situation.

Comment: If this is a "brand new" iPhone, then the retailer where it was purchased should exchange it.

Comment: If you have another charger and cable try them. Also - make sure that the socket you're using for the charger actually works - try plugging in the charger to another socket. If you have an older iPhone which charges using the same cable/charger, try them on your new phone. likewise, try the new cable/charger on your old iPhone.